# How to return a sorted list of keys based on the nth entry of the list stored in the value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I've got a dictionary that I'm storing data for musical chords with the name as the key and the tone values in a list as the values.  I'd like to be able to sort if based on the various values in the contained lists.  Here's an example of the data:

```
chord_bank = {
        '7sus':[0,5,7,10],              # c           f    g      bb
        'maj7sus':[0,5,7,11],           # c           f    g         b
        'sus4':[0,5,7],                 # c           f    g        
        'maj':[0,4,7],                  # c         e      g
        'min':[0,3,7],                  # c      eb        g        
        'sus2':[0,2,7],                 # c    d           g
}
```

On a basic level, I want to just extract the keys to a list, which is easy enough:

```
chords = [*chord_bank.keys()]
print(chords)

# ['7sus', 'maj7sus', 'sus4', 'maj', 'min', 'sus2']
```

But then I also would like to be able to sort on a given item in the values list.  For example:

```
chords = sorted(chord_bank.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1][-1])
print(chords)

# [('sus4', [0, 5, 7]), ('maj', [0, 4, 7]), ('min', [0, 3, 7]), ('sus2', [0, 2, 7]), ('7sus', [0, 5, 7, 10]), ('maj7sus', [0, 5, 7, 11])]
```

The problem here is that instead of a list of chord names, I'm getting a list of tuples.  I know I can use a comprehension now like this `chords = [ i[0] for i in chords]` after I get the list of tuples, but I'm trying to see if I can get this accomplished within the sorted function itself.

I've tried looked for possible solutions form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866204/sort-list-of-dictionaries-based-on-keys-inside-the-list), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211374/sort-a-list-of-entries-according-to-a-given-column-and-return-the-list-of-indice), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439646/sorting-list-of-dictionaries-with-list-as-values-based-on-second-item-of-list-va) and I've tried out some naive solutions like these, which failed in ways I expected:

```
chords = sorted(chord_bank, key=(chord_bank.get)[1])

# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

and

```
chords = sorted(chord_bank.values(), key=lambda kv: kv[1][-1])

# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

So I'm looking for a solution that can directly return a list of keys (chord names) sorted on whichever indices of the values list I choose.

Answer (score 2):

```py
def sorted_cord_names(chord_bank: dict, index: int):
    return sorted(chord_bank.keys(), key=lambda key: chord_bank[key][index])

>>> chord_bank = {'7sus': [0, 5, 7, 10], 'maj7sus': [0, 5, 7, 11], 'sus4': [0, 5, 7], 'maj': [0, 4, 7], 'min': [0, 3, 7], 'sus2': [0, 2, 7]}
>>> sorted_cord_names(chord_bank, -1)
['sus4', 'maj', 'min', 'sus2', '7sus', 'maj7sus']
```